# Buddy memory allocation

Tags: memory, memory-management, operating-system, allocation

I have the array of size *n* which represents my main memory. I can not use operator new, I have only access to that memory so every data structure must use only that array to store data. I am trying to build memory allocator which will be able to quickly find free portions of that memory (array) and also free them. I want to build tree structure over that array - buddy memory allocation - but I am struggling with understanding few concepts.

How exactly is buddy system looking for free chunk of memory using binary tree ?

How should I store this tree in the array ?

How can I create new nodes of that tree (should I just reserve enough space for my tree at the beginning of the program or "allocate" it dynamically - but how to do it simply) ?

I kinda have the answers to these questions but I am struggling with fully understanding it. I would appreciate every clear answer and help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Take a look at [binary heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap). This structure represents a tree
   inside an array.
2. Take a look at Aleksandrescu's small object allocator from his [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201704315). In the second chapter (AFAIR) he describes a practical approach to embed ~8-~128 bytes long structures inside an external byte array with no overhead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just one more thing - how can I search for free chunk of memory in this tree since node only contains information about its size and if it is split node, free node or occupied node (the memory which this node represents is used).  Should I just search for particular chunk of the memory- if it is occupied search further or divide some bigger block of free memory into smaller and allocate it ?

Comment: Again, read second chapter from Aleksandrescu book - he describes one of algorithms for unoccupied chunk lookup inside specially formatted external byte array (with zero overhead because with his approach only free chunks contain format, non-free ones contains only data). Maybe it'll give you some insights.